# problem with alsa installed

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I'm using linux for the first time. I installed alsa 1.0.24 in my system running Ubuntu 12.04. After installing, I tried to play some files using command `aplay -vv abc.wav`, it started playing but I can't hear the sound.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/oss/ sndstat1
Sound Driver:3.8.1a-980706 (ALSA v1.0.24 emulation code)
Kernel: Linux developer-OptiPlex-170L 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:41:14 UTC 2012 i686
Config options: 0

Installed drivers:
Type 10: ALSA emulation

Card config:
Intel ICH5 with AD1980 at irq 17

Audio devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG

Synth devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG

Midi devices: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG

Timers:
31: system timer

Mixers: NOT ENABLED IN CONFIG
```

If i use the command `aplay -l` it shows the error as `no soundcards found...`. But actually sound card is there. If I run `cat /proc/asound/cards`, it shows the sound card name as:

```
0 [ICH5           ]: ICH4 - Intel ICH5
                  Intel ICH5 with AD1980 at irq 17
```

And even after installing `alsamixergui`, and if I run `alsamixer', it shows`cannot open mixer: no such device`.

Whether it's the problem with alsa or soundcard?

Answer (score 1):

You still have 1.0.24, but the installation attempt seems to have broken something.

Anyway, the easiest way to update sound drivers (if you really need to do it) is to [upgrade the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080) itself.